# Postgresql тихо дохнет при INSERT

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

У меня есть БД, и этот код работает,

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO raspisanie(raspisanie, grade,dated,userid) VALUES(%s, %s,%s,%s)", raspi_mas)
    base.commit()
```

А при попытке

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (userid, grade) VALUES(%s, %s) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING", (user_id, text))
base.commit()
```

БД перестаёт отвечать, не выдаёт никаких ошибок, и просто тихо умирает. И даже следуюзщий за этим `print("ok")` не отрабатывает, значит, обработчик ошибок тут тоже бессилен.
Единственное, в чём может быть проблема - `ursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (userid text UNIQUE,grade text);")`
Уникальный ID. Но ведь код дальше тоже не работает!

Вот код функции без обработчиков ошибок, но в терминал никакая ошибка не выводится. Выводится только if и всё. И зависает

```
user_id=str(user_id)
text=str(text)
print("if")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (userid, grade) VALUES(%s, %s)", (user_id, text))
base.commit()
print("ok")
```

Comment: UNIQUE тут непричём, оно в любом случае останавливает код

Comment: тихо умереть может только в одном случае, запрос возвращает какое то исключение, которые вы где то выше перехватываете и игнорируете. Либо по другим причинам не видите что выдало исключение

Comment: @Mike Проблема в том, что даже без try и ON CONFLICT, оно тихо уходит. Подскажите пожалуйста, как выцепить эту ошибку?

Comment: скрипт при ошибке обязан упасть и ошибку выдать. невозможно сказать почему у вас не выдает. пробуйте сделать небольшой тестовый скрипт где кроме этих строк ничего не будет. Если опять не выдает, разбирайтесь со своей средой разработки. Если все таки выдает в простом варианте, то смотрите что в скрипте ошибки подавляет

Comment: может у тебя где-то транзакция незакрытая? Тогда он тихо ждёт, когда можно будет продолжить. Стоит проверить, есть ли у тебя таймаут для запросов.

Comment: Я понятия не имею что это было, но я переписал точь-в-точь код ещё раз, и всё работает уже 4 дня.